# Meaning of choose function with a negative number

Tags: combinatorics, laplace-transform

I have encountered an expression for an inverse Laplace transform, and now I am wondering whether it is correct or maybe there is some error. More likely I don't understand it. so here goes:

$$
g(p)(e^{ap}+\beta)^{-c} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{0\leq n\leq t/a -c}\left(\begin{array}[c] - -c\\ n\end{array}\right)\beta^n f(t-ac-an)
$$

Where $a,c>0$.

So what is the meaning of this?
Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136348/intuition-behind-negative-combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\binom xn$ is
$$\binom xn=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1)}{n!}$$
for any nonnegative integer $n$ and any complex number $x$.